# run a standlone .cs file within a asp.net application in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using the vs2010 to build a asp.net web application,sometime I want to do some test,so I have to create a new .cs file,but when I click the debug button,the vs will start the whole web application rather than the standlone .cs file.

In java,I use eclipse as my IDE,if I want to do some test in my web applicatio,I just create a new .java which own the "main" method,then I can run this file by "run as java appliation",so this .java will start.

I wonder if I can do the samething in vs2010?

BTW,how to do some output in the console within vs2010?

In java,within a servlet,I can use the `System.out.println("xxx")` within the method,when a request comes from the client,the "xxx" will be printed in the console of the eclipse,but in vs when I try `"Console.WriteLine("xxx")`,there is no output in the vs console, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new C# project within your solution alongside your ASP.NET project, and if you want console-based output in that C# program, you need to make sure it's a C# Console Application.

To add a new project to your solution, right-click the solution header in the Solution View, and select "Add Project...". You should definitely **not** just insert a `.cs` file into your ASP.NET project.

Comment: Even I create a new c# project,when I debug the .cs ,the web application will start also.

Comment: @hguser: You should be able to right click on the new project in the Solution Explorer and choose "Set as Startup Project".  Then when you run/debug, it will start that application.  You can also right click on a specific project and choose Debug and then "step into instance" or "start new instance".

Comment: Yes - the C# program needs to be set as the startup project. You can't run two programs at the same time when you start debugging (well, technically you *can*, but that's outside the scope of this question).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to run the single class? Is there any special requirement?

Here a procedure to create windows console application if that's what you want to do:

1. Go to File-> New -> Project
2. Select 'windows' in installed templates.
3. Select 'Console application'

By doing this, you'll get a single .cs file and Console.WriteLine will definitely work in it.

Comment: For example,in xxx.aspx.cs,I have to read some xml file,but I have never used the xml related libary,so I want to create a single class to do some xml reading releated test,any way?

Comment: Are you trying to create a real world application or are you just programming to enhance your skills? You are saying that you created *.aspx.cs file.  Have you tried windows console application?

Answer (score 0):

You can write to Visual Studio 2010 output window by including System.Diagnostics and using Debug.Write()